# how to force a localizable WinForms app to use the (default) Language property

Tags: c#, winforms, localization

I have a WinForms app in 4 different languages. The whole app was written in English, but I never set the Localization to en, or en-US. Is there a way to use to force the Language property to (default) from code. For instance, let's say that the current thread is in Portuguese, I close all forms, change the CultuInfo of the current thread to use the (default) language and reload all forms again. Is there a way o doing that?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you are searching for the [`NeutralResourcesLanguage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.neutralresourceslanguageattribute.aspx) class. You use this attribute  in your `AssemblyInfo.cs` file to set the default culture of an application:

```
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("en-US")]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: NeutralResourcesLanguage doesn't exists

Comment: it's full name is System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguage