# Resources.resx and Resources.en-US.resx , which one will be chosen?

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I'm working on the project which contains two resource files:

`Resources.resx` and `Resources.en-US.resx`

[image]

At the beginning the application used German as default language and English was added later. Based on some criteria I choose the UI language from my code so it is NOT set automatically.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4872235/how-to-force-a-localizable-winforms-app-to-use-the-default-language-property) I see that default language is en-US.

**Question:** which resource should be used if I call

```
if (instLanguage == 0)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
}
```

before `InitializeComponent();` ?

I'm asking because the program behaves differently in different Windows 7 versions. In standard Win 7 eng. and ger. versions en-US resource is used, but Windows 7 English with German language pack takes default resource file.

Comment: Why not run it and see? Use ProcMon to see what files are being read... or just load a resource that's different in each file.

Comment: @RodneyRichardson I ran and saw different behavior as written in my question. I'm asking here about defined behavior

Comment: It isn't obvious why you are having this problem.  You are however playing a very dangerous game, overriding the thread's culture has many side effects and is a rich source for bugs.  Clearly you ought to swap the resource files here and make the English one your default one.

Comment: @HansPassant what is the better way to set UI language and what kind of bugs should I expect?

Comment: There is no good way to set it, your user already has it set the way he wants and doesn't like you to change it.  You get bugs when the worker threads run with a different culture, they'll use the operating system default.  A SortedList created by a thread suddenly isn't sorted anymore when you use it in the UI.  Etcetera.  .NET 4.5 finally has a solution for it, CultureInfo.DefaultXxx.

Comment: Don't worry too much about changing the Culture Code dynamically.  Yes, you have to do it right...but it isn't hard.  We do it all the time.  If you change teh nature of the question...I will post relevant code.